# C# New Class Instance return null

Tags: c#, class, null, instantiation

I try to instantiate a new Character class but it returns null (even though some variables of the class are instantiated).

I tried to make a contructor but the Character class contains a ScriptableObject (CharacterClass) and I can't make a complete constructor.

What can I do ?

**Character Class Fields, Constructor & Initialization Method :**

```
    public string _className;
    public CharacterClass _characterClass;

    public bool _isTheFocus;

    public int _level;
    public int _targetXP;
    [ProgressBar(0, "_targetXP")] public int _currentXP;

    public CharacterStat _HP;
    public int _currentHP;
    public int _currentShield;

    public CharacterStat _physicalAttack;
    public CharacterStat _magicalAttack;
    public CharacterStat _physicalDefense;
    public CharacterStat _magicalDefense;

    public List<CharacterState> _characterStates;

    public Character() {
        _className = "";
        _isTheFocus = false;

        _level = 0;
        _currentXP = 0;
        _targetXP  = 0;

        _HP              = new CharacterStat();
        _currentHP     = 0;
        _currentShield = 0;

        _physicalAttack  = new CharacterStat();
        _magicalAttack   = new CharacterStat();
        _physicalDefense = new CharacterStat();
        _magicalDefense  = new CharacterStat();

        _characterStates = new List<CharacterState>();
    }

public void Initialization() {
        _className = _characterClass._className;

        _level           = 1;
        _HP              = new CharacterStat(_characterClass.HP);
        _physicalAttack  = new CharacterStat(_characterClass.PhysicalAttack);
        _magicalAttack   = new CharacterStat(_characterClass.MagicalAttack);
        _physicalDefense = new CharacterStat(_characterClass.PhysicalDefense);
        _magicalDefense  = new CharacterStat(_characterClass.MagicalDefense);

        InitializeHPGrowth();

        InitializeStatGrowth(_physicalAttack.Value, ref physicalAttackDie);
        InitializeStatGrowth(_magicalAttack.Value,  ref magicalAttackDie);

        InitializeStatsPercent(ref _physicalDefense.BaseValue);
        InitializeStatsPercent(ref _magicalDefense.BaseValue);

        InitializeStats();

        ExpNextLevel();
    }
```

**Method to Instantiate a new Character Class :**

```
public void InitClassToBufferCharacter(CharacterClass targetClass) {
        bufferCharacter = new Character();
        bufferCharacter._characterClass = targetClass;
        bufferCharacter.Initialization();
    }
```

**The BufferCharacter result :**

[BufferCharacter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mAAxw.png)

The BufferCharacter was initialized by Inititalization Method (level, hp, etc.) but still null.

Comment: Where is `BufferCharacter` defined? How is it defined. How is the code ran against it? What else might write it? Please provide a complete, minimal, verifyable example.

Comment: It is not null, but it's `ToString()` method returns the string "null" which is then displayed in the debugger

Comment: The BufferCharacter is defined in another class

Comment: What is the exact code? How did you determine that the object was null? Was there an exception? If yes, at what line does it throw? You should clarify this question more.

Comment: As @KlausGütter has noted, the "Character class" instance is not resulting in `null`, its just the `ToString()` implementation for the instance.  So you should just be able to use it, without an issue. It would be good to get an understanding of, if you're getting an issue later down in the execution of the code.

Comment: @PierreREYNAL Welcome to Stack Overflow. In terms of your question on not being able to make a Constructor, is there a particular reason, you can't do... 
```public Character(CharacterClass characterClass) {...}``` ?
I'm not a Unity developer - but from a C# perspective, there is little technical difference between setting it via the Constructor and setting the field value.